# How best to determine if a String contains only null characters?

Tags: java, string, java-8, char, null-character

What's the right way to check if a string contains null characters only?

```
String s = "\u0000";
if(s.charAt(0) == 0) {
   System.out.println("null characters only");
}
```

Or

```
String s = "\0\0";
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
   if(s.charAt(i) == 0) 
       continue;

   else break;

}
```

Both work. But is there a better and more concise way to perform this check. Is there a utility to check if a string in java contains only null
characters(`\u0000` OR `\0`) ?

And what is the difference between `'\0'` and `'\u0000'`?

Comment: Hmm.  I am hard-pressed to think of a **valid** use-case that involves testing to see if a string contains just NUL characters.  (The only use-cases I can think of involve treating non-text data as text ... and that's conceptually wrong.)

Comment: @StephenC, my service needs to call a downstream server, which is returning a parameter in json body say "eCode", based on this I need to check if there's something went wrong in downstream server, so if this string is empty OR contains only null characters than everything is fine, other wise if "eCode" contains anything else than I need to returned an error response to the upstreams.

Comment: OK ... so why is a server sending you a string that contains NUL characters in a JSON response?  That is ... umm ... bad design.  Are you sure that you haven't misunderstood the spec?  (Might it actually say "an empty string or null"?  There is a null value in JSON.)

Comment: No I have even tested calling the service, they are returning null character string, I initially thought it should be null or "" empty string but as my test cases got failed than I realized that they are returning something else, and that's indeed a bad design, I concur, But you know, I have to deal with it as I don't have the ownership of other service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression

to match one or more `\u0000`

```
boolean onlyNulls = string.matches("\u0000+");  // or "\0+"
```

use `*` instead of `+` to also match the empty string

---

<sup>(the stream [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67513220/15793316) by Sweeper is my preferred solution - IMHO it better resembles the intended task, despite I would use `'\u0000'` instead of `0`)</sup>

Answer (score 9):

A `char` literal (in Java) can be written multiple ways (all of which are equivalent). For example,

```
System.out.println('\u0000' == '\0');
System.out.println('\u0000' == 0);
```

Will output

```
true
true
```

because a `char` is a 16-bit integral type in Java. And all three of `\u0000`, `\0` and `0` are the same value. As for finding if a `String` contains only `0` `char` values - simply iterate it. Like,

```
boolean allNulls = true;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) != 0) {
        allNulls = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and if you want a **consise** way to do the test, put the above code into a method/function.

Comment: Okay so we have to iterate over every single char and compare with '\u0000', we have no util available for that?

Comment: @tusharRawat What do you mean by a "util"? Anything you use will, at some point or another, loop through each character of the string. It's just that you might not see the loop in the code you write. After all, how do you know if _every_ character is NUL without checking every one of them?

Comment: Yeah understand @Sweeper, what your are saying, I know internally also the utility is going to do the same, 1-by-1 character comparison, but the entire purpose of having a utility is if something is built already just use it in development don't reinvent the wheel, I hope you understand what I am saying.

Comment: @tusharRawat In that case, I'm going to refer to Stephen C's comment on your question - this is not a common thing to do, at all (it is also possible that you _shouldn't_ be doing this at all). There's no reason for such a utility to exist. My answer or user15793316's answer is probably the shortest solutions you can get.

Comment: @Sweeper It's not better (because it creates temporaries) but `if (s.replaceAll("\u0000", "").length() == 0) { /* */ }` is shorter. At least I think it is.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch why do developers come up so often with creative detours but fail to directly use the method expressing the intent? When you want to check whether a string *matches* a certain pattern, just use, e.g. `s.matches("\0*")`, instead of replacing the matches (`replaceAll` also uses the regex engine) with empty strings, only to test whether only empty strings will remain. If you are worried about temporary objects, use `Pattern.compile(...)` to reuse the part whose construction is truly expensive (the `Matcher` is negligible).

Comment: @Holger Hang on. I'm looking for a forest, but all I can see is these stupid trees.

Comment: Never mind. I just see this pattern so often and really wondered why this happens so often. Perhaps, there is something about APIs or documentation we could improve…

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `chars()` as an `IntStream`, then use `allMatch`:

```
if (yourString.chars().allMatch(x -> x == 0)) {
    // all null chars!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a predefined way to check it, and I think the second one you mentioned is the correct way of testing for the same

Answer (score 0):

Other than the other answers (all valids), I've just found a one liner, based on `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`:

```
StringUtils.containsOnly(<string>, '\u0000')
```

Just a note: this method manages the empty string "" returning `true`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the existing String methods like
`trim` and `isEmpty` with combination for this.
consider this:

```
String s = "\u0000";
s.trim().isBlank()
```

Comment: But this would also be true for `\t\r` and other all-whitespace inputs.

Comment: Yes it would, i haven't considered this.

Comment: When you use `isBlank()` as in your code example, there is no sense in doing a `trim()` first. `trim()` would only be necessary when you use `isEmpty()` as described in the first sentence of you answer.

Answer (score -1):

\u0000 is Unicode value , The console output is a space

```java
Stream.of("\u0000","\0\0","jack", "luca")
  .filter(s -> !s.trim().equals(""))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

output:

```
jack
luca
```

Comment: This is incorrect because it also prints `true` for some strings that contain non-NUL characters.

Comment: The console output of `\u0000` depends on the particular console.